# Convergence in distribution of difference of two random variables given convergence of sum

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n, Y_n, X$ and $Y$ denote random variables and $\Rightarrow$ denote convergence in distribution. I know that

1. $X_n \Rightarrow X$, $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$ and
2. $X_n + Y_n \Rightarrow X + Y$.

Does it follow that $X_n - Y_n \Rightarrow X - Y$?
(By Cramer-Wold it would then follow that $(X_n, Y_n) \Rightarrow (X,Y)$.)

If not, I also know that $X_n \geq 0$, $Y_n \geq 0$, $X \geq 0$ and $Y \geq 0$.

Comment: What if $X_n =X' \stackrel{d}{=} X$ and $Y_n = Y'  \stackrel{d}{=} Y$ for all $n$ and $X' - Y' \stackrel{d}{=} X-Y$. Does this allow to deduce that $X'+Y' \stackrel{d}{=} X+Y$? I guess not. Likewise for the conclusion  on joint convergence.

Comment: Is this a question or a hint? I don't have a particular counterexample at hand (if there exists some). The typical counterexamples for such joint convergence in distribution only use that $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$ but not the second point that the sum (difference) is also converging in distribution to the sum (difference).

Comment: It is a hint. There should be a counterexample of the type I proposed with $X$ and $Y$ supported on finitely many points. E.g. $P(X=i,Y=j) = p_{ij}$, $P'(X'=i,Y'=j)=p_{ij}'$ for $i,j \in \mathbb{N}_0$. You obtain equations which should not have a unique solution. Concerning the $n$ and your worry in the comment: your question is not a question of relative compactness: if 1. holds, then also the sequences $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are relatively compact (Prohorov's theorem!). You only worry about uniqueness of the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to thomas for the clarification and the hint how to construct such a counterexample.

Let $(X,Y)$ and $(X', Y')$ be distributed as follows:

\begin{array}{l|ccc} X|Y & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 \\
2 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0
\end{array}

and

\begin{array}{l|ccc} X'|Y' & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 \\
3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}

Then $X,X',Y$ and $Y'$ are uniformly distributed on $\{ 1, 2, 3\}$ and thus 
$X \stackrel{d}{=} X'$ and $Y \stackrel{d}{=} Y'$. Moreover, $X+Y$ and $X'+Y'$ are uniformly distributed on $\{ 3, 4, 5 \}$ and thus $X + Y\stackrel{d}{=} X' + Y'$. But $X - Y \stackrel{d}{\neq} X' - Y'$.